# Can you daisy chain Alienware monitors with an Alienware m15 r6?

Tags: daisychaining

I have an Alienware m15 r6 with an Alienware AW2720HFA monitor, I have just bought a second monitor, exactly the same model but can’t seem to get the daisy chain set up.  How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The Alienware AW2720HFA monitor does not support DisplayPort Daisy Chaining. HDMI does not support Daisy Chaining at all.

The monitor has the following display connectors:

- HDMI *Input* (×2)
- DisplayPort *Input*

Only monitors that have a DisplayPort *Output* connector support Daisy Chaining.